# Create a pandas dataframe from a nested lists of unequal lengths

Tags: python, list, pandas, nested

So I have a list as follows:

```
aa = ['aa1', 'aa2', 'aa3', 'aa4', 'aa5']
bb = ['bb1', 'bb2', 'bb3', 'bb4']
cc = ['cc1', 'cc2', 'cc3']
```

Which is then created into a nested list:

```
nest = [aa, bb, cc]
```

I want to create a dataframe as follows:

```
aa   bb   cc
aa1  bb1  cc1
aa2  bb2  cc2
aa3  bb3  cc3
aa4  bb4  nan
aa5  nan  nan
```

I've tried:

```
pd.DataFrame(nest, columns=['aa', 'bb', cc'])
```

But results is such that, each list is being written as a row (as opposed to a column)

Comment: `list(itertools.izip_longest(aa, bb, cc))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `zip_longest` function from `itertools` does this:

```
>>> import itertools, pandas
>>> pandas.DataFrame((_ for _ in itertools.zip_longest(*nest)), columns=['aa', 'bb', 'cc'])
    aa    bb    cc
0  aa1   bb1   cc1
1  aa2   bb2   cc2
2  aa3   bb3   cc3
3  aa4   bb4  None
4  aa5  None  None
```

If you have an older version of pandas you may need to wrap `zip_longest` in a list constructor. On older Python you may need to call `izip_longest` instead of `zip_longest`.

Comment: I was waiting for you to post this (-:

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work either.
`module itertools has no attribute izip_longest`. I'm using Python 3 if that helps and pandas version `0.20.3`

Comment: I was waiting one of those silly windows 10 updates (84%) and the Mac has only python2.7 - it was renamed to zip_longest in newer Python IINM.

Comment: Wait, a new version of pandas will support iterators for the data argument?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it will take a generator expression so you don't have to create an huge list in memory anymore.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why the constructor takes a generator but not an iterator is beyond me. [issue[2193](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2193)]

Comment: @PauloScardine oh wow, I hadn't realized, But strangely, it **only** accepts generator types, as far as I can tell, but it won't accept just plain `zip_longest` iterators, but if I do the silly `(row for row in zip_longest(...))` it works

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

```
pd.DataFrame(nest, ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']).T

    aa    bb    cc
0  aa1   bb1   cc1
1  aa2   bb2   cc2
2  aa3   bb3   cc3
3  aa4   bb4  None
4  aa5  None  None
```

---

**Option 2**
Homebrew `zip_longest`

```
f = lambda x, n: x[n] if n < len(x) else None
n, m = max(map(len, nest)), len(nest)

pd.DataFrame(
    [[f(j, i) for j in nest] for i in range(n)],
    columns=['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
)

    aa    bb    cc
0  aa1   bb1   cc1
1  aa2   bb2   cc2
2  aa3   bb3   cc3
3  aa4   bb4  None
4  aa5  None  None
```

Comment: Sorry, Option 1 doesn't seem to work for me.
`3 columns passed, passed data had 5 columns` is the error

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  `pd.__version__`

Comment: `0.20.3` is the version of pandas

Comment: Btw, Option 2 works too. It looks complicated though!

Comment: @Kvothe I agree, I Paulo's answer and wanted to try it myself without `zip_longest`.  I'm still concerned about my first option not working.  It should have.  I copied and pasted your code and then ran mine.  I'm using the same version.  Anyway, you have a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'value':nest},index=['aa', 'bb', 'cc']).value.apply(pd.Series).T
Out[1297]: 
    aa   bb   cc
0  aa1  bb1  cc1
1  aa2  bb2  cc2
2  aa3  bb3  cc3
3  aa4  bb4  NaN
4  aa5  NaN  NaN
```