# Replace all None's in a Pandas data frame with a tuple of None's

Tags: python, pandas

So I am working on some code for an NLP application. An [interesting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431660/create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-nested-lists-of-unequal-lengths) on Stackoverflow creates a dataframe from lists of unequal lengths. Taking the code from that solution with tuples in the input:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

aa = [('aa1',4), ('aa2',3), ('aa3',2), ('aa4',2), ('aa5',1)]
bb = [('bb1',8), ('bb2',6), ('bb3',4), ('bb4',4)]
cc = [('cc1',3), ('cc2',2), ('cc3',1)]
nest = [aa, bb, cc]

df = pd.DataFrame((_ for _ in itertools.zip_longest(*nest)), columns=['aa', 'bb', 'cc'])
df
```

you get a dataframe which looks like this:

[image]

A subsequent step requires all elements in the data frame to be tuples.

I have tried this:

```
df.replace({None : (None,None)})
```

While it seems to run without error, it does not carry out any replacement. 
Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: What about `df.replace({None: (None, None)}, inplace=True)`?

Comment: @roganjosh thanks, unfortunately not, just tested ít. The problem is with what is in the brackets or that this `replace` function is not able to replace None's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be using `pandas.DataFrame.apply()` and `pandas.Series.map()` like this:

```
df.apply(lambda ds: ds.map(lambda x: x if x != None else (None, None)))
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems this could work, while I don't know why.

```
df = df.where(df!=[None], '(None, None)')
```

It may be better to use "np.nan" than "None" in DataFrame, as [fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) could be used.

Comment: Thanks it did work certainly with the example in the question, but there was some kind of robustness issue, in my example it generated the error `ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64`, I was investigating the cause of this when @dispayname posted his answer.

Comment: that's great answer :)