# Writing multiple lists of different lengths to same rows in Python

Tags: python, xml, csv, parsing, beautifulsoup

I've got some files of big data to parse through. Each file has repetitions of certain tags but only one case of others. For example, each file has parents for `name` and `date` which only show once in every block of data but have many children like `patent citations`, `non-patent citations`, and `classification`.

So I parse through finding all cases of each three of these children and store them every iteration of parents in each file to individual lists. The problem is that the children are always of different lengths and I want to write them all on *one row* of a CSV file.

For example for *one iteration* in a file for my list **inputs** are like:

```
Name = [Jon]
Date = [1985]
Patcit = [1, 2, 3]
Npatcit = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Class = [9, 10]
```

And I want an **output** written to a CSV file to look like:

```
Name  Date  Patcit  Npatcit  Class
Jon   1985     1       4       9
               2       5       10
               3       6      
                       7
                       8
(Repeat next name and date iteration on the next row)
```

My code runs through the file like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
grant = soup.findAll("grant")

  for info in grant:
    cite = soup.findAll("us-citation")
    names = soup.findAll("name")

    Patcit = []
    Npatcit = []
    Class = []

    for item2 in cite:
      for items in item2.findAll("patcit"):
        pat = items.find("patent-citation-title")
        Patcit.append(pat)

.
.
.
.
The same for the other 2 lists
```

And then for example writing for only the *Patcit* list would look something like:

```
for inv_name in zip(names):
  for j in range(int(len(Patcit))):
    datapatcit = Patcit[j]
    writer.writerow[(inv_name).text, datapatcit]
```

Using a `writer = csv.writer(name, dialect = excel)`

So this is the issue. I cannot figure out a good way to get the **output** how I want it above.

Comment: You can replace `for items in item.findAll("patcit"):pat =items.find("patent-name")   Patcit.append(pat)` with `Patcit = [items.find("patent-name") for items in item.findAll("patcit")]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a pandas dataframe from a nested lists of unequal lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431660/create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-nested-lists-of-unequal-lengths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you establish the longest list in each input, you can pad the other lists with empty strings.

```
Name = ["Jon"]
Date = [1985]
Patcit = [1, 2, 3]
Npatcit = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Class = [9, 10]
data = {"Name":Name, "Date":Date, "Patcit":Patcit, "Npatcit":Npatcit, "Class":Class}

max_n = max([len(x) for x in data.values()])
for field in data:
    data[field] += [''] * (max_n - len(data[field]))

data
{'Class': [9, 10, '', '', ''],
 'Date': [1985, '', '', '', ''],
 'Name': ['Jon', '', '', '', ''],
 'Npatcit': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 'Patcit': [1, 2, 3, '', '']}
```

Then write to CSV using your preferred method.  I'd choose Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)

df
  Class  Date Name  Npatcit Patcit
0     9  1985  Jon        4      1
1    10                   5      2
2                         6      3
3                         7       
4                         8
```

**UPDATE**
if you need to do this over multiple iterations (for example, over multiple cases of `info` in `grant` in your sample use case), you can use `concat`.
I'd also recommend moving the padding operation into a function, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def pad(data):
    max_n = max([len(x) for x in data.values()])
    for field in data:
        data[field] += [''] * (max_n - len(data[field]))
    return data

# CSV 1
Name = ["Jon"]
Date = [1985]
Patcit = [1, 2, 3]
Npatcit = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Class = [9, 10]
data = {"Name":Name, "Date":Date, "Patcit":Patcit, "Npatcit":Npatcit, "Class":Class}
df = pd.DataFrame(pad(data))

# CSV 2
Name = ["Sally"]
Date = [19995]
Patcit = [9,8,7]
Npatcit = [1,3,5]
Class = [4, 10,15]
data = {"Name":Name, "Date":Date, "Patcit":Patcit, "Npatcit":Npatcit, "Class":Class}
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(pad(data))])

df
  Class   Date   Name  Npatcit Patcit
0     9   1985    Jon        4      1
1    10                      5      2
2                            6      3
3                            7       
4                            8       
0     4  19995  Sally        1      9
1    10                      3      8
2    15                      5      7
```

Comment: And what if I want to iterate through many files? This does overwrite the previously stored results but I have many to parse through. I know this is a bit of a basic question but I haven't had much experience using pandas at this point.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly, but if you need a number of CSVs, just use a counter and update the filename on each iteration.  E.g. `fname=f"output_{ct}.csv"; df.to_csv(fname, index=False)`

Comment: You also don't need Pandas, per se - I think the key intuition is to pad the uneven row lengths, and then assemble them in some kind of table format to write to CSV.  Numpy, Pandas, even just reading row-by-row with core Python I/O methods will work.

Comment: Sorry that's not what I mean. I mean that the files that I'm parsing have multiple instances of each of these lists. I do feel that the pandas dataframing might help me simplify my code when it comes to writing the csv so I'd like to use your method. So I'd need something that would write `data` each time I run through my loop and compile it all into one CSV. Instead what your code currently does is writes over each `data` before it.

Comment: You should just be able to use `pd.concat()`.  But it's hard to know exactly how `Date` and `Name` are related to `grant` and the loops you have in your data.  If you update your post showing two input rounds' worth of data, and where each variable gets defined, it'll be easier to understand your problem, and I can update my solution accordingly.

Comment: I've added where the names of the inventors occur (once per run) on how my code currently is written - this writes the name more than once into the CSV file instead of creating white space underneath as you can tell. I stated before though that I filled the list `Name` with each name but this was for simplicity for keeping all data I want to write in the same form.

Comment: These changes are in the 'main body' and the 'writer' portion.

Comment: See my updates, I'm still not sure I understand your question correctly, but this should give you enough to go off of.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing `pandas` I added a simple counter at the beginning of the loop and if statements inside the main loop to run the function given by @andrew_reece called `pad(data)` which looks like:

```
counter == 0
main for loop in grant:
  lists = []
  .
  .
  .
  def pad(data):
    .
    .
    .
    if counter == 0:
      df = pd.DataFrame(pad(data))
    else:
      df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(pad(data))])

    counter = counter + 1
```

We could have also used just a `True` or `False` statement instead to 'count'. This ensures that the very first parse is able to 'trigger' the first concatenation.

Thanks again, @andrew_reece for the aid.